# `\immediate\write` not working on first page

Tags: write, immediate

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newwrite\foo
\openout\foo=foo.foo

\begin{document}

\immediate\write\foo{A}
\immediate\write\foo{B}
\lipsum
\immediate\write\foo{C}
\lipsum
\immediate\write\foo{D}

\end{document}
\closeout\foo
```

When compiling the above, foo.foo contains

```
C
D
```

If I remove the `\immediate`s, it also includes `A` and `B` as expected.  What causes this behavior?

Comment: `\immediate\openout\foo=foo.foo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need

`\immediate\openout\foo=foo.foo`

so that it is opened before the first page is shipped out and also if you want to explicitly close it you need

`\closeout\foo`

before `\end{document}` as no commands after `\end{document}` are executed.
However the file stream will be closed cleanly if it is still open at the end of the run so `\closeout` is not needed unless you need to input the file during the same run.

Answer (score 5):

You can note that the console displays

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ray.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
No file ray.aux.
A
B
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2] [3] (./ray.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/ams
fonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on ray.pdf (3 pages, 27002 bytes).
Transcript written on ray.log.
```

which means that the file is not yet open at the time `\immediate\write\foo{A}` is scanned.

*Every* operation related to writing in files not prefixed by `\immediate`  will be delayed at the next shipout. This includes `\openout` and `\closeout`.

So you should do `\immediate\openout` as well.

By the way, note that `expl3` only opens write for writing immediately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\openwritestream}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanT { #1 }
   {% * version also allocates
    \iow_new:c { g_ray_write_#2_iow }
   }
  \iow_open:cn { g_ray_write_#2_iow } { #3 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\writestream}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \iow_now:ce }% expanded
   { \iow_now:cn }% not expanded
   { g_ray_write_#2_iow } { #3 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\closewritestream}{m}
 {
  \iow_close:c { g_ray_write_#1_iow }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\openwritestream*{foo}{\jobname.foo}

\newcommand{\test}{xyz}

\begin{document}

\writestream{foo}{A}
\writestream{foo}{B}
\lipsum
\writestream{foo}{C}
\lipsum
\writestream{foo}{D}
\writestream{foo}{\test}
\writestream*{foo}{\test}

\closewritestream{foo}

\end{document}
```

This is the contents of the `ray.foo` file:

```
A
B
C
D
\test 
xyz
```

Note the difference: `\write` always performs full expansion on the argument, whereas `\writestream` doesn't, unless called as `\writestream*`.